# Transfer big videos from iPhone to Windows PC

Tags: iphone, photos, data-transfer

To transfer files from my iPhone 8 (running iOS 11 and iOS 12) to my Windows 10 PC, I use a USB cable and simply copy the files with Windows Explorer.

If I try to transfer a file over 500MB in size, I get the following Windows 10 error:

```
Can't read from the source file or disk.
```

Then I have to unplug the iPhone and restart. I tried with iTunes.
I tried changing cables, ports (USB2 and USB3) and computers.

It has been working fine before Apple introduced the HEIF/HEVC formats in iOS 11.

What is causing this and how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: how about uploading it to cloud, google drive ect.. of course it will depend on your internet speed and data limit

Comment: out of curiosity, what happens if you try the other way around, upload from W10 to iPhone

Comment: @Buscar웃 I wanted to avoid installing an other software only to transfer photos. Never tried W10 to iphone (Should not work).

Comment: I understand that you want to avoid this, but can you install a trial version of any third-party iTunes alternative (iMazing, iExplorer, Dr.Phone, etc.) and check if you will be able to transfer this video just to understand if the issue is in Explorer or there's something else?